# Why does CreateDIBSection return NULL?

Tags: c, winapi, gdi

I am trying to get the DI Bitmap of a section of an application's client area. The client area is a dialog window and I have used the CreateDIBSection function which is returning NULL with GetLastError returning 0.

Here is the code:

```
TRESULT GetDIBPage(_IN HWND inobj, \
           _INOUT void **outobj){

 //Variable declarations
 void *tmpbits = 0;
 char *tmpstr = 0;
 BITMAPINFO tmpbmpinfo;
 BITMAPINFOHEADER tmpbmphdr;
 POINT tmppoint;
 HDC tmphdc;
 HWND tmphndwindow = 0;
 int tmpn = 0;
 int ret = 0;
 int ret2 = 0;

 //Argument checks
 if(inobj == NULL){
  return TPTRISNULL;
 } //EndIf
 if(outobj == NULL){
  return TPTRISNULL;
 } //EndIf

 //Initializations
 tmphndwindow = inobj;

 //Main logic

 //Start to get the DIB.

 //Get a device context for the window.
 tmphdc = GetDC(tmphndwindow);

 //Get the width in bytes.
 tmpn = (3 * 408);

 //Calculate the stride.
 if((tmpn % 4) > 0){

  //Round to the nearest 32 bits.
  tmpn = (((tmpn / 4) + 1) * 4);

 } //EndIf

 //Calculate the DI bitmap size.

 //Set the tmpbmphdr variable.
 tmpbmphdr = tmpbmpinfo.bmiHeader;

 //Set the members of the bitmap info
 //header
 tmpbmphdr.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
 tmpbmphdr.biWidth = tmpn;
 tmpbmphdr.biHeight = 600;
 tmpbmphdr.biPlanes = 1;
 tmpbmphdr.biBitCount = 24;
 tmpbmphdr.biCompression = BI_RGB;
 tmpbmphdr.biSizeImage = (tmpn * 600);
 tmpbmphdr.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
 tmpbmphdr.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
 tmpbmphdr.biClrUsed = 0;
 tmpbmphdr.biClrImportant = 0;

 //Get the DI Bitmap.
 CreateDIBSection(tmphdc, \
          &tmpbmpinfo, \
          DIB_RGB_COLORS, \
          &tmpbits, \
          NULL, \
          0);

 //Check if tmpbits is NULL.
 if(tmpbits == NULL){
  tmpstr = (char*)calloc(513, sizeof(char));
  sprintf(tmpstr, \
      "Creating the DIB failed.\n %d", \
      GetLastError());
  MessageBox(NULL, \
         tmpstr, \
         "Error", \
         MB_OK);
  free(tmpstr);

  return TPTRISNULL;
 }

 //Free variables
 ReleaseDC(tmphndwindow, \
       tmphdc);

 //Returns
 *outobj = tmpbits;
 return TSUCCESS;

} //End GetDIBPage
```

When I run the program, the error message appears indicating that tmpbits was set to NULL.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `tmpbmpinfo` not initialized. `tmpbmphdr = tmpbmpinfo.bmiHeader;` - senseless - this is not pointer.

Comment: Thanks RmMm. I am so accustomed to using pointers that I forgot about the standard when assigning objects.

Comment: if you use `BITMAPINFO* tmpbmpinfo = &tmpbmpinfo.bmiHeader;` and then `tmpbmphdr->biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);` this will be correct. however better simply init `tmpbmpinfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);` as is

Comment: Please do _NOT_ use backslash to escape newlines when simply splitting calls over multiple lines. It is unnecessary and difficult to read. You can remove every single backslash in the posted code and it will compile just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The summary based on @RbMm 's comments and the [Alpha Blending a Bitmap example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/alpha-blending-a-bitmap) is the [BITMAPINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-bitmapinfo) structure isn't initialized properly. The initialization is initializing the temporary `tmpbmphdr`. It's also necessary to zero memory like [Alpha Blending a Bitmap example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/alpha-blending-a-bitmap) does.

```
    // zero the memory for the bitmap info 
    ZeroMemory(&bmi, sizeof(BITMAPINFO));

    // setup bitmap info  
    // set the bitmap width and height to 60% of the width and height of each of the three horizontal areas. Later on, the blending will occur in the center of each of the three areas. 
    bmi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = ulBitmapWidth = ulWindowWidth - (ulWindowWidth/5)*2;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = ulBitmapHeight = ulWindowHeight - (ulWindowHeight/5)*2;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;         // four 8-bit components 
    bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = ulBitmapWidth * ulBitmapHeight * 4;

    // create our DIB section and select the bitmap into the dc 
    hbitmap = CreateDIBSection(hdc, &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, &pvBits, NULL, 0x0);
```